# Saving R plot as numeric array object

Tags: r

I have a series of X and Y coordinates describing the shape of US state legislative districts, and I would like to use a function I have to run the Harris corner detector on them to identify how many visually significant corners they each have. My current workflow involves plotting every shape and saving that plot using `jpeg("temp.jpg")`, then loading in that .jpg file using `imager::load.image()`.

This feels really wasteful, and won't work for users without write access to the working directory or with other graphics device settings. Is there a way to store an R plot directly to a numeric array without having to write the file to disc first?

Example below:

```
x = c(1,1,2,2)
y = c(1,2,2,1)

png("temp.jpg")
plot(NA, xlim=c(0,3), ylim=c(0,3))
polygon(x,y, fill="grey")
dev.off()

img.array = imager::load.image("temp.jpg")
img.array
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, if you put a minimum reproducible example in here that we can cut and paste into our R sessions to try and store the plot to an array for you, you will get more responses on here... then we can validate solution as well, instead of just guessing for you. Thanks :)

Comment: I updated to add a minimal example, but TBH I'm not sure it should help devise a solution any. Happy to be wrong though!